# Fluent-bit, How can I use strftime in path

Tags: fluent-bit

my log file name contains the current date, like my_log_210616.log

and I need to tail the file in fluent-bit. I tried with,

```
[INPUT]
Name    tail
Path    /var/log/my-service/my_log_%y%m%d.log

[OUTPUT]
Name stdout
Match *
```

but it doesn't watch the file. I replaced `my_log_%y%m%d.log` with `my_log_210616.log`, then it works.

How can I use strftime in the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a path that matches any date. Since fluent-bit will read the log files from their tail you won’t get data from the older files.

You could also add ’Ignore_Older 24h’ to the input config. This will ignore files with modified times older than 24 hours. Using ’Ignore_Older’ with a parser that extracts the event time works even better.

You could also do more elaborate filtering by file name in a lua filter.